# How can I fall back the wrong element onErrorReturn of a project reactor flux?

Tags: project-reactor, reactive

Lets say I have a flux where an element throws an error.

```
 Flux.just("aeiou","aeio").map(x -> {
           if(!x.endsWith("u")){throws Exception;}
           return x;})
      .onErrorReturn(/*This only accepts a new element*/)
      .map(x -> x+";")
      .subscribe();

 Flux.just("aeiou","aeio").map(x -> {
           if(!x.endsWith("u")){throws Exception;}
           return x;})
      .onErrorResume(/*This doesn't do the next steps*/)
      .map(x -> x+";")
      .subscribe();
```

I want something like this

```
 Flux.just("aeiou","aeio").map(x -> {
           if(!x.endsWith("u")){throws Exception;}
           return x;})
      .onErrorReturn(x -> x + "u")
      .map(x -> x+";")
      .subscribe();
```

Documentation seems wrong
http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_fallback_method

```
Flux.just("key1", "key2")
   .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k)) 
   .onErrorResume(e -> getFromCache(k)); //k not resolved here
```

Comment: The documentation is not only correct but a viable solution to your problem.

Comment: @abetteroliver Well, I want to use the value of k to fall back, but it's not resolved. I even pasted the code block and the parser doesn't like.

Comment: e = Throwable, not a String in the last block, k should be the String

Comment: The example in the documentation calls `onErrorResume` on the stream created by `callExternalService`. Yours doesn't.  You would use `flatMap` instead of `map` to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is correct.

```
 Flux.just("key1", "key2")
   .flatMap(k -> callExternalService(k)) 
   .onErrorResume(e -> getFromCache(k)); //k not resolved here
```

k is not getting resolved because **k is declared in flatMap as a local variable**. It is not visible to onErrorResume(). If you declare k above the pipeline, i.e. before Flux.just then it will be resolved.

Secondly, to your other question

```
Flux.just("aeiou","aeio").map(x -> {
       if(!x.endsWith("u")){throws Exception;}
       return x;})
  .onErrorReturn(x -> x + "u")
  .map(x -> x+";")
  .subscribe();
```

You have to refer the API docs. onErrorReturn() can allow you to return a fallback value. But that fallback value is kind of hardcoded, i.e. you will not get the value of x there. You can simply hard code the value to u but that may not solve your purpose.

I suggest to look at `onErrorResume(Function<? super Throwable,? extends Publisher<? extends T>> fallback)` as this allows you to write a function where you can put some logic to do additional processing.

This allows you to get back a publisher, so you can do something like below.

```
.onErrorResume(e -> { //get the value of x
                       String x = <>;// you will have to write logic to get the value of x here, as it will not be available directly                          
                       return Flux.just(x+"u");
                       })
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my problem. I don't seem to find a way to get x since it changes through each step of the flux.

Comment: Well one way could be to simply pass it in the Exception object and then you can retrieve it in onErrorResume. Basically create a custom Exception object and then set the value of x in that custom exception object before you throw the Exception. Then when you handle it in onErrorResume you can get X out of the Exception object.

Comment: There is something new: onErrorContinue(BiConsumer<Throwable, Object> consumer). I can directly capture the object with error and the exception. Then the flux continues with the next elements, the only problem is that it doesn't rethrows a new object.

Comment: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onErrorContinue-java.util.function.BiConsumer-